# C - Inline asm patching at runtime

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86, patch

I am writing a program in C and i use inline asm. In the inline assembler code is have some addresses where i want to patch them at runtime.

A quick sample of the code is this:

```
void __declspec(naked) inline(void)
{
      mov eax, 0xAABBCCDD
      call 0xAABBCCDD
}
```

An say i want to modify the 0xAABBCCDD value from the main C program.
What i tried to do is to Call VirtualProtect an is the pointer of the function in order to make it Writeable, and then call memcpy to add the appropriate values to the code.

```
DWORD old;
VirtualProtect(inline, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old);
```

However VirtualProtect fails and GetLastError() returns 487 which means accessing invalid address. Anyone have a clue about this problem??
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It seems like there ought to be a better way of solving the real problem that made you want to do this. Also how are you deciding on the real value of 0xAABBCCDD? There are probably ways you can get that substitution to happen "for free", depending upon where that address comes from.

Comment: (Also guessing this is Win32/MSVC here from the syntax and system call - you might want to indicate that explicitly with tags and/or in the question).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to make a hook in the target process so it jumps to your function? If so you should be `VirtualProtect`ing the block of memory you'll be overwriting to make the hook, not your function, and you'll also need to jump back out of your codecave (either `call` + `ret` or `jmp` to a specific address at the end of your function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
int X = 0xAABBCCDD;

void __declspec(naked) inline(void)
{
      mov eax, [X]
      call [X]
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the address is not static. I will get it at runtime.

Comment: Well yes, of course you will get it at runtime. And then you will execute a line of code that says `X = the_address_I_got_at_runtime;` before invoking your assembly function.

Comment: Yeah right. But forgot to mention something important. What i want to do is patch the code and inject it to another process, and run it from there. Not in my process. But the point is that i want to WRITE a value at runtime anywhere in the inline asm. Thats why i am trying to mark the function as writeable with virtualprotect. The problem is that VirtualAlloc fails...

Comment: Well, that makes it a different question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

How to do it *to another process* at runtime,

1. Create a variable that holds the program base address
2. Get the target RVA (Relative Virtual Address)
3. Then calculate the real address like this PA=RVA + BASE
4. then call it from your inline assembly

You can get the base address like this

```
DWORD dwGetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcessID)
{
    TCHAR zFileName[MAX_PATH];
    ZeroMemory(zFileName, MAX_PATH);

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, true, dwProcessID);
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessID);
    DWORD dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;

    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = { 0 };
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32))
        {
            do
            {
                if (wcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, L"example.exe") == 0)
                {
                    dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    return dwModuleBaseAddress;
}
```

Assuming you have a local variable and your base address

```
mov     dword ptr ss : [ebp - 0x14] , eax;
mov     eax, dword ptr BaseAddress;
add     eax, PA;
call    eax;
mov     eax, dword ptr ss : [ebp - 0x14] ;
```

You have to restore the value of your Register after the call returns, since this value may be used somewhere down the code execution, assuming you're trying to patch an existing application that may depend on the eax register after your call. Although this method has it disadvantages, but at least it will give anyone idea on what to do.